# IBM MobileFirst 7.1 - Error when making request from Android Client

Tags: java, android, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

When making a call to an MFP adapter, i'm getting this response

```
{  
   "statusCode":400,
   "errors":[  

   ],
   "isSuccessful":true,
   "statusReason":"Bad Request",
   "html":{  
      "body":"",
      "html":"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml",
      "xmlns":"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   },
   "responseHeaders":{  
      "Content-Language":"en-US",
      "Date":"Thu, 11 Feb 2016 14:47:03 GMT",
      "Content-Length":"0",
      "Expires":"Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT",
      "Set-Cookie":[  
         "JSESSIONID=0000e8OwOu5nRy5GHcnq5aOyJ6W:-1; Path=/; HttpOnly",
         "JSESSIONID=0000kr3JjAeXlHQyeCFsWm9Sagx:-1; Path=/; HttpOnly"
      ],
      "Connection":"Close",
      "X-Powered-By":"Servlet/3.0",
      "Cache-Control":"no-cache=\"set-cookie, set-cookie2\""
   },
   "warnings":[  

   ],
   "totalTime":200,
   "responseTime":198,
   "authRequired":true,
   "info":[  

   ]
}
```

The thing is, when i make the same request to my websphere server through a browser, or calling the adapter directly from eclipse I get the expected response.

Relevant Android code

**The call to the MFP server**

```
public static void validateUserId(MobileFirstActivity activity, String userId, boolean saveUserId,
                                      WLResponseListener listener) {
        ValidateUserIdRequest validateUserIdRequest = new ValidateUserIdRequest(userId, saveUserId);
        activity.performResourceRequest(validateUserIdRequest, listener);
    }
```

**The ValidateUserIdRequest object**

```
class ValidateUserIdRequest implements ResourceRequest {

private final String userId;
private static final String appVersion = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
private final String saveUserId;
private static final String devicePrint = "Android";

public ValidateUserIdRequest(String userId, boolean saveUserId) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.saveUserId = String.valueOf(saveUserId);
}

@Override
public int setEndpointResource() {
    return R.string.ValidateUserId;
}

@Override
public void setParams(WLResourceRequest resourceRequest) {
    resourceRequest.setQueryParameter("params",
            ResourceUtils.convertMapToParamString(
                    userId, appVersion, saveUserId, devicePrint));
}

@Override
public String setRequestMethod() {
    return WLResourceRequest.GET;
}
```

**The method that actual performs the request**

```
public void performResourceRequest(final ResourceRequest resourceRequest, final WLResponseListener listener) {
    if (!isConnectedToMfpServer) {
        connectToMfpServer(new WLResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(WLResponse wlResponse) {
                isConnectedToMfpServer = true;
                performResourceRequest(resourceRequest, listener);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(WLFailResponse wlFailResponse) {
                isConnectedToMfpServer = false;
                listener.onFailure(wlFailResponse);
            }
        });
    } else {
        try {
            URI endpoint = new URI(getString(resourceRequest.setEndpointResource()));
            WLResourceRequest request = new WLResourceRequest(endpoint, resourceRequest.setRequestMethod());
            resourceRequest.setParams(request);
            request.send(listener);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**The utility method that converts the String[] params to a compatible string.**

```
public static String convertMapToParamString(String... params) {

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
            stringBuilder.append("'").append(params[i]).append("'");
            if (i != (params.length - 1)) {
                stringBuilder.append(",");
            }
        }
        stringBuilder.append("]");

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

**convertMapToParamString gives me this as a result** [as per the documentation for Javascript based adapters](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/server-side-development-category/invoking-adapter-procedures-native-android-applications/)

```
['mbltest3','1.0','false','Android']
```

I get the correct parameters on my MFP server, but the request is still bad.
What else could I try?

Comment: I think the issue is not between the client and MFP, but rather between MFP and your backend. Meaning the "bad request" error was sent by your backend. Can you share your adapter call as well?

Comment: @NathanH You are correct, My cookie wasn't getting attached to the request properly which was giving me this error.

Comment: @hitch.united can you please move the answer of this question from a Comment and into an Answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the cookie for my request was not being properly attached resulting in the 400 error.